# В чем разница этих двух записей кода, объясните новичку попроще

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Учу ООП и на уроках нас учат, что для того, чтобы вывести на экран значения локальных свойств экземпляра класса, необходимо создать дополнительный метод, и выглядит это вот так:

```py
class Point:
    def set(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)

p = Point()
p.set(1, 2)
print(p.get())
```

Но почему бы не вывести значения свойств через дополнительный объект класса, так запись будет проще?

```py
class Point:
    def set(self, x, y):
        return x, y

p = Point()
е = p.set(1, 2)
print(e)
```

В чем разница этих записей и как правильно?

Comment: *Я в пайтоне не силён*, но по моему второй вариант просто будет возвращать заданные пользователем в функции значения, а в первом будет у класса задавать значения `x`-а и `y`-а.

Answer (score 4):

В первом варианте

```
def set(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

значения `x` и `y` присваиваются свойствам экземпляра класса. После этого в свойствах экземпляра `p.x` и `p.y` хранятся указанные значения.

В втором варианте

```
def set(self, x, y):
    return x, y
```

ничего никуда не присваивается и вообще эта функция по сути ничего не делает.

Аналогия: в первом варианте функция `set()` кладет в левый и правый карманы ваших брюк `x` и `y` конфет. А функция `get()` сообщает потом сколько конфет в каком кармане лежит, конфеты там остаются лежать и можно с ними делать все, что угодно. Во втором варианте вы никакие конфеты никуда не кладете, а функция `set()` просто сообщает, сколько конфет кто-то хотел бы положить в карманы, но не положил.

---

> почему бы не вывести значения свойств через дополнительный объект класса

В вашем коде нет никакого "дополнительного объекта класса".

Comment: О, я об этом и написал в комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый и доступный новичку ответ. Учусь по курсам в Ютубе и поэтому не имею возможности спросить у преподавателя. Только вот почему нет дополнительного объекта класса, он же экземпляр. Разве "е" таковым не является?

Comment: Нет, ``e`` таковым не является. Это просто переменная. ``p`` - объект класса, потому что ``p = Point()``.

Comment: Это переменная класса к которой я обращаюсь через метод класса? В ней храниться(записывается) кортеж (1, 2)? Я могу работать с этим кортежем через другие методы класса? Наверно вопросов слишком много, но хочется уловить суть темы.

Comment: ``e`` вообще никак не связана с классом. И работать через методы класса вы с ней никак не сможете.

Comment: @SamKnight  `e` хранит возврат исполнения метода (а проще, функции), а конкретнее просто кортеж (1,2) и ничего общего у переменной `e` и объектом класса нет

Answer (score 0):

Попробую описать на примере кода

```py
class Point:
    def set(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def get(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
    def set_incorrect(self, x, y):
        return x, y
```

установим значения в экземпляр класса

```py
p = Point()
p.set(1,2)
print(type(p), p.x, p.y)
```

Вывод

```
<class '__main__.Point'> 1 2
```

все верно `p` - это экземпляр класса `Point`

Если воспользоваться вашим вариантом, то можно увидеть, что объект не изменится и смысла в таком использовании нет

```py
p = Point()
p.set(1,2)
e = p.set_incorrect(10000, 20000)
print(f"это возврат не корректного метода {e}\nс типом данных {type(e)}")
print(f"а это хранит объект p {p.x, p.y}\nс типом данных {type(p)}")
```

Вывод

```
это возврат не корректного метода (10000, 20000)
с типом данных <class 'tuple'>
а это хранит объект p (1, 2)
с типом данных <class '__main__.Point'>
```

Заключение. В реализации парадигм ООП обязательное использование обращения к полям и методам внутри класса через `self`. Иначе нет необходимости писать классы и можно использовать функциональный подход.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнительное пояснение! Теперь все встало на свои места.